# I am trying to make a half circle in sketchup

Tags: sketchup

I'm trying to create essentially a half pipe shape in sketchup but having trouble. I can get an arc and build the shape, but it won't extrude.

[image: Half Pipe]

Thanks,

Dirk

Comment: And how this is related with programming?

Comment: this belongs on [su]

Comment: It's a computer program. I also found a related question via google on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

create a vertical rectangle then create your half circle on it.

Or using the tape measure, make sure all geometry is coplanar.

[GIF explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ12m.gif)